# MobaXterm SE BLOQUEAN SOLO

Tags: ubuntu

Bueno Cuento con un sistema cargado en un servidor en Ubuntu ,  para la administración utilizo MobaXterm todo perfecto, pero el problema va en la parte de la inactividad , ya que después de estar inactivo por unos minutos en dichas aplicaciones se bloquea de alguna manera y me manda este mensaje (se que me da el mensaje que el causante es un programa , pero no tengo algun programa que lo bloque o algo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo la obligación de volver a reconectarme , no se si es problema de mi red o algo

Comment: Voy a suponer que te conectas usando SSH. Revisa la configuración de los servidores porque se suele configurar un tiempo de inactividad para desconexión automática.

Comment: Si utilizo el protocolo SSH , desconozco en si donde configurar eso en el MobaXterm , pero lo peculiar es que al parece solo pasa en mi red , porque otras no sucede eso

Comment: No expliqué bien, me refería a que es una configuración del servidor. Igualmente, es muy raro si pasa solo en tu red y no en otras. ¿Es estable tu conexión?

Comment: Te sirve esto? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265201/set-ssh-idle-timeout-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Si mi red es estable, dudo que se se por parte del servidor , probé con otro servidor y el error sigue persiste , probé en otra laptop en mi red habitual y tiene le mismo problema